# Prevent users from unwanted changes to their personal scripts

Tags: mediawiki

Before considering additions to `MediaWiki:Common.js` or `MediaWiki:Vector.js`, it makes sense to test it in limited scope. I assume that this is what user-specific scripts can be used for provided that [$wgAllowUserJs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgAllowUserJs) has been set.

I suggested to enable user scripts to the sysop and I claimed that no harm could be done because the scripts would only be executed for the logged-in user who loads the page, so he/she is responsible for what he/she does with the scripts. But then I realized that user scripts can be changed by other users. Is there a way - besides having a great team of wiki administrators - to prevent users from unwanted changes? Or should I better withdraw my request?

I wished that there were a built-in lock but this [seems not to be the case](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interface/JavaScript#Personal_scripts).

Is there a way to restrict changes in the user namespace to the same-name logged-in user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User scripts are not terribly useful for testing changes to site scripts, since they won't replace site scripts, just run alongside them. They are rather meant to empower people to be able to write tools for themselves, without having to depend on administrators to install it. Which they do, but they are also a maintenance burden, result in spurious bug reports and enable some social-engineering attack vectors.

If you want to ease testing, I'd move away from site scripts entirely, and use [the Gadgets extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Gadgets) instead.

Comment: *since they won't replace site scripts* -- you mean that starting with a feature may be easy but not changing it later? The *Gadgets* seem interesting for the purpose of interface customization. So thanks for pointing me into that direction.

Comment: Would you say that the bottom line is that user scripts do more harm than good?

Comment: Yeah, testing modifications to a site script is a major PITA; with gadgets you can create a stable and testing version and disable one when enabling the other. Also, people tend to forget about updating their user scripts and then time is wasted on debugging why the site is broken for them. User scripts are good for empowering users (sadly, Gadgets still makes administrators the bottleneck - everyone [agrees](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Gadgets/Roadmap#Gadgets_3.0) that should change but no one had time to work on it), not good for much else.

Comment: ...so it really depends on your userbase. If there are users who are able to write their own tools, you want to enable them but you don't want to make them administrators (this is typical for large community wikis with untrusted users), user scripts make sense. In a company environment where people can just ask the wiki operators in such cases, not so much. Testing changes to site scripts is definitely not a use case I'd enable user scripts for.

Comment: Seems I'm getting the idea now (I also tried reading a bit in the manual meanwhile). Wouldn't user scripts help non-admins to create new gadgets to suggest to admins then?

Comment: Yeah, if your users are capable of building their own scripts then enabling user scripts can help with "crowdsourcing" new gadgets.

Answer (score 0):

Only now I read in [Wikipedia:User scripts, section *A word about security*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:User_scripts#A_word_about_security):

> However, unlike a standard userspace template, you don't need to worry about vandalism – JavaScript code in user space is protected from other users. Only interface administrators and the user in whose space the script lies can edit it.

So Wikipedia has exactly the built-in security I was hoping for. But such information is not as easy to find in the description of the [switch within the MediaWiki manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interface/JavaScript):

> If `$wgAllowUserJs` is set to true, users can customize the interface for only themselves by creating and importing personal scripts in user subpages with *lowercase* titles

This inconspicuous and brief note suggests it is implemented in the MediaWiki software itself.

Comment: That "lowercase" is completely bogus, FWIW. Casing of user JS subpages is irrelevant.

Comment: @Tgr If you know this for sure, wouldn't it be good to correct it in the manual? But **it may depend on the case-setting** of the wiki config. We started our company wiki fully case sensitive (which turned out to be counterproductive, more work to do) and then switched to case-insensitive initials. I remember that with our starting config, page names only differing in the case in the initial to an existing page are shown as red-links. So, since most MediaWikis are run with case-insensitive initials, `vector.js` will most likely by silently forwarded to `Vector.js` etc.

Comment: Subpage names are never capitalization-insensitive. And yeah, skin names need to be lowercase, you are probably right that the text was referring to that. Any user subpage which ends in `.js` will be treated as a personal script, though.